# IntelliJ Idea Live Template remove current line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, replace, selection, live-templates

Does IntelliJ IDEA's `Live Template` feature support the ability to remove the current line(s) the user is interacting with before replacing it with the live-template content?

I know I can use the parameter `$SELECTION$` to take the current highlighted code, but is there a way to delete the rest of the current line(s)?
(Similar action would be like the `"Keymap -> Editor Actions -> Delete Line"` keyboard command).

I don't know if I may have missed it in the docs: 
[Jetbrains live-templates variables documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html)

Example Setup of Live-template (for Java):
[image: Example Setup of Live-template]

Example usage would be to highlight the `String` parameter in: `System.out.println("highlight me!");` and use `Ctrl + Alt + J` to open available templates and convert it:

Example:
[image: Example Code]

Comment: No, you can't delete code with live templates. You may want to use a custom SSR based inspection instead: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation. This is not possible in the current version of IntelliJ Idea. Closing question.